# Node.js cluster (pm2) - Closed WebSockets receive messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, websocket, pm2

I'm trying to build a simple yet scalable chat app using Node.js and WebSockets. I'm using RabbitMQ as a message broker between my Node instances. I'm using pm2 for Node clustering behind Nginx.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes WebSockets that have already closed are receiving new messages instead of open ones.

Here is the code for my WebSocket server:

```js
var url = require('url');
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var rabbit = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://localhost');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

const q = "messages";

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', function onConnection(ws) {

    console.log('got websocket connection');

    rabbit.then(function(conn) {
        ws.conn = conn;
        console.log('consumer connected to rabbitMQ');
        return conn.createChannel();
    }).then(function(ch) {
        console.log('consumer channel created');
        return ch.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
            console.log('consumer asserted queue');
            return ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
                console.log('received message from rabbitMQ: ', msg.content.toString());
                if (ws.readyState === 1) {
                    if (msg && msg.content) 
                        ws.send(msg.content.toString());
                } else {
                    console.warn('Websocket is not open, state is ', ws.readyState);
                }
            }, { noAck: true });
        });
    }).catch(function handleConsumerRabbitErr(err) {
        console.warn('Handled rabbit consumer error:', err.stack);
    });

    ws.on('message', function onMessage(msg) {

        console.log('got websocket message');

        if (ws.conn) {
            ws.conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {
                console.log('producer channel created');
                return ch.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
                    console.log('sending ' + msg + ' to rabbitMQ');
                    return ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer(msg));
                });
            }).catch(function handleProducerRabbitErr(err) {
                console.warn('Handled rabbit producer error:', err.stack);
            });
        }

    });

    ws.on('close', function onClose() {
        console.log('websocket closing');
    });
});
```

My Nginx config:

```
http {

    upstream nodejs {
        server localhost:3000;
    }

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade  {
        default upgrade;
        ''  close;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name 192.168.45.45;
        root /vagrant/static;

        # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
        if ($scheme = http) {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location /ws/ {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        }

        location /app/ {
            proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running the app with the following command (creates 2 nodes on my VM):

`$ pm2 app.js -i 0 --name chat`

Here is the output of `pm2 log` after sending a WebSocket message, refreshing the page, and sending two more messages:

```
[STREAMING] Now streaming realtime logs for [all] processes
0|chat     | got websocket connection                # Initial websocket connection on node 0
0|chat     | consumer connected to rabbitMQ
0|chat     | consumer channel created
0|chat     | consumer asserted queue
0|chat     | got websocket message
0|chat     | producer channel created
0|chat     | sending test to rabbitMQ
0|chat     | received message from rabbitMQ:  test   # Websocket received message from RabbitMQ, as expected
0|chat     | websocket closing
1|chat     | got websocket connection                # Page refresh, new websocket connection on node 1
1|chat     | consumer connected to rabbitMQ
1|chat     | consumer channel created
1|chat     | consumer asserted queue
1|chat     | got websocket message
1|chat     | producer channel created
1|chat     | sending test to rabbitMQ
0|chat     | received message from rabbitMQ:  test   # ERROR - old websocket received message from RabbitMQ!
0|chat     | Websocket is not open, state is  3      # Note these two lines are from node 0
1|chat     | got websocket message                   # Sent another message without refreshing the page
1|chat     | producer channel created
1|chat     | sending test to rabbitMQ                # This one succeeds, and it alternates from here
1|chat     | received message from rabbitMQ:  test
```

I've found that it succeeds on every nth message sent, where n is the number of websockets I've opened (aka. the number of times I've refreshed the page), regardless of whether the websockets have been closed or not.

My expectation is that after a WebSocket is closed, it's `message` event shouldn't fire anymore. Clearly that's not the case though.

What can I do to make sure the WebSocket stops receiving messages after it's closed?

Answer (score 0):

If I had [RTFM for RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html), I would have learned that consuming from a queue is round-robin by default. In fact, what I was looking for was [pub/sub with exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-javascript.html).